# is it possible to make /boot partition after installing linux distribution

Tags: boot

I right now I have 3 partitions: one each for UEFI firmware, swap and the root partition.
I was wondering if it is possible to make new partition in which I can put `/boot` in my case after installing linux distribution?

*I know it is possible during installation, but that is not what I want*

Comment: Why not just mount your ESP at `/boot`?

Comment: I am sorry ESP ?

Comment: EFI System Partition.

Comment: I am already mounting the EFI partition in the root partition at `/boot/efi`